# Creating an SQL join in Mediawiki's php framework

Tags: php, mediawiki

**Background:**

Mediawiki's PHP framework provides functions for creating SQL statements to be executed against the application. Creating a simple SELECT FROM WHERE statement is easy and well documented, but I'm trying to create a JOIN statement and I don't understand the documentation. The examples are fragmented and disjointed.

**Current attempt:**

The SQL I'm trying to recreate is as follows. Using phpmyadmin I've tested this code and it returns the results I need:

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.user_name, user.user_real_name, user.user_email
FROM user
LEFT JOIN ipblocks ON user.user_id = ipblocks.ipb_user
WHERE ipblocks.ipb_id IS NULL
```

Translating this into Mediawiki's framework looks something like this, but this code doesn't work. The function documentation is [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_31/php/classWikimedia_1_1Rdbms_1_1Database.html#a3b03dd27f434aabfc8d2d639d1e5fa9a).

```
$result = $this->dbr->select(
    array( $this->dbr->tableName( 'user' )),
    array( 'user_name', 'user_id', 'user_email' ),
    array( 'ipb_id' => 'NULL'),
    __METHOD__,
    array( 'GROUP_BY' => 'user_id DSC' ),
    array( 'ipblocks' => array( 'LEFT JOIN', 'user_id=ipb_user' ) )
);
```

The SQL generated by this code can be checked by calling [selectSQLText](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_31/php/classWikimedia_1_1Rdbms_1_1Database.html#ab8c96bd23e66bcf3dde074f096c601c6)() instead. This function returns the generated SQL rather than executing it. The calling convention is the same. THis results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT user_name,user_id,user_email
FROM `user`
WHERE ipb_id = 'NULL'
```

I can see why the function has returned this, but I don't understand why the last two parameters have been ignored. The GROUP_BY and JOIN parts have been ignored. Why is this and how do I correct the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an user of Mediawiki, I've just glossed over the function documentation. As for grouping, I believe you should use `GROUP BY` array key, not `GROUP_BY`. As for joins, I think you must include `ipblocks` table in `$table` parameter in order to use it in `$join_conds`.

So, try this:

```
$result = $this->dbr->select(
    array( 'user', 'ipblocks' ),
    array( 'user_name', 'user_id', 'user_email' ),
    array( 'ipb_id' => null),
    __METHOD__,
    array( 'GROUP BY' => 'user_id DSC' ),
    array( 'ipblocks' => array( 'LEFT JOIN', 'user_id=ipb_user' ) )
);
```

Comment: You don't actually need all the tableName calls (in fact they'll probably result in double prefixing if your tables use a prefix). Also you should use `NULL`, not `'NULL'`.